Reducing downtime of Statefulset K8S
I am currently in the process of migrating applications from DO droplets (VPS) to Kubernetes (K8S). The old system applications are mostly stateful, so I am facing challenges in minimizing downtime.
For instance, when I move a service to a StatefulSet in K8S, the downtime is relatively high, often exceeding 1 minute. This downtime includes the time taken to terminate the old pods (to handle remaining traffic) and the time to wait for the new pod to become ready (including the time to attach the volume).
I am wondering if there is an existing solution where new pods are created but don't serve traffic until the old pods have successfully terminated their tasks. This would reduce the downtime to just the time taken to terminate the old pods.
I have 3 approach ideas:

One approach is to relocate the app to a Deployment and employ a separate app to distribute the unique KEY. After that, we can use Redis "redlock" to stop new pods from handling traffic until the old pod has shut down and released the lock.

The second option is to maintain the app in two StatefulSets. Another app can be used to manage the update process using a "Blue Green" strategy. When a new StatefulSet is created, it remains locked, similar to the first approach, until the old StatefulSet is terminated by the app orchestration.

Using consistent hashing: may be challenging as it requires numerous changes from the current disorganized system.


Has anyone implemented a system like this or have any ideas about how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Hi I think your second options is a good idea
I suggest two options for your situation
Option 1. Apply blue-green strategy by using service mesh(istio)

look docs at https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#bookinfo

(example yaml after setup istio)
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: your-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - your-service.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: your-service
        subset: blue
      weight: 100
    - destination:
        host: your-service
        subset: green
      weight: 0
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: your-service
spec:
  host: your-service
  subsets:
  - name: blue
    labels:
      version: blue
  - name: green
    labels:
      version: green

Option2. Other simple solution with readinessprobe
Why don't you use readinessprobe to control traffic
See docs at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes
For example
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: your-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "your-service"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: your-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: your-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: your-container
        image: your-image
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10


I wish my solution is helpful for you

Thanks for your response. If choosing option 2, I think instead of using locking, I can check if the readiness probe becomes ready for the first time (when the corresponding old pod is terminated as signaled by an orchestration app) to start serving traffic and init queues, kafka,... But I'm wondering, is there any existing solution out there, or do I have to control this kind of update strategy by building an orchestration app?

Unfortunately, Kubernetes primarily offers two deployment strategies: Rolling Update and Restart. However, these strategies alone might not fully meet your specific requirements... So if you want to deploy with other strategy (like blue/green strategy,) you should use service mesh or build orchestration app
